# Is there a special method to remove a shortcut from a desktop?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, desktop-application, shortcut

I created a shortcut (.lnk) file on the desktop using the IShellLink interface similar to the code described at the bottom of [this page](http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/5954-how-do-i-create-desktop-shortcuts-from-c/).

So my assumption was that to remove this shortcut I could simply call [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the .lnk file, but evidently it is not enough... if I do that I get a remnant of the shortcut file that looks like this:

[image]

But what is interesting is that if I browse files in the desktop folder, say with Windows Explorer, the .lnk file is not actually there. What I see is some artifact on the desktop GUI surface.

Any idea how to remove a shortcut (the way Microsoft wants it done?)

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Should've done more research before posting, sorry everyone. I'll keep it though for those who also run into it. You need to call the following after deleting the .lnk file: `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_DELETE, SHCNF_PATH | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, pDeletedFilePath, NULL);`

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer.  As per the FAQ, answering your own questions is not only allowed, it's encouraged. :-)

Comment: To add context: this is merely to refresh explorer (which also displays the desktop icons). It may happen automatically or with a small time delay on some verisons of windows. When deleting the file through the Shell API ShFileOp (which appears overkill), the explicitrefresh is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, per suggestion above, here's the API that needs to be called afterwards to refresh the shell:

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_DELETE, SHCNF_PATH | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, pDeletedFilePath, NULL);
```

Comment: Can we delete a folder shortcut in the same way?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPalagummi: IDK. It's been awhile since I've been dealing with this. You'll have to try it yourself and post the result.